# Расположение SEO текста

Tags: html, seo, текст

Доброго времени суток всем, недавно меня попросили выполнить одну задачу, которая поставила меня в тупик, от подобной реализации решили отказаться но мне все же стало интересно как реализовать данное действие и возможна ли вообще его реализация.

Собственно задача состоит в том, чтоб некий текстовый блок в коде страницы отображался сверху, а физически на сайте он присутствовал снизу. Я понимаю что можно это сделать отступами при абсолютном позицианирование, но мне почему то кажется что это не верный вариант. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным и для чего это вообще хотят делать?

Comment: `.footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}`

Comment: я знаю одно применение. Люди с ограниченными возможностями также используют интернет. Текст на странице они могут  и не смочь прочитать (к примеру, плохое зрение) и они используют специальные читалки, которые читают текст с экрана.  Так вот они будут текст зачитывать подобный, а обычные пользователи скорее всего его никогда и не увидят.

Comment: @KoVadim Для людей с ограниченными возможностями разработан стандарт Accessible Rich Internet Applications (WAI-ARIA) https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles

Comment: Подобное реализовано в jQueryMobile как поп-ап http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/popup/ , с целью экономии места для моб. устройства.

Comment: @nikant25 я в курсе всего этого. Но некоторые разработчики пытаются их  перехитрить.

Comment: @KoVadim похоже, что здесь не настолько благородные намерения.

Answer (score 1):

Для данной задачи лучше использовать возможности флексбокса, в частности CSS-свойство **order**. Вот пример разметки:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex p {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.first {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="second">
    <p>Второй блок.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first">
    <p>Первый блок.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

В примере контейнеру задается свойство **display:flex**. Чтобы дочерние блоки шли вертикально, добавляется свойство **flex-direction:column**. А чтобы блоки с текстом выстроились в нужном порядке, используется свойство **order**.